# Are duplicate widgets (ex: desktop and mobile menu appearing at the same time) a violation of WCAG?

Tags: accessibility, wcag

Occasionally I will audit a website for accessibility that displays the mobile hamburger menu in the same screen width with the regular desktop menu. This is obviously a terrible blunder in terms of UX, and I could imagine it would greatly inconvenience disabled users (as any other redundancy).

But my question - is that a violation of any WCAG success criterion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that having more than one of the same nav menu is a terrible practice, it's not necessarily a WCAG failure. There are some circumstances that could cause it to be:

1. If both menus share the same ID, then it will be a violation of [SC 4.1.1](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Understanding/parsing.html).
2. If there's any difference between the content or ordering of the two menus, then it will be a violation of [SC 3.2.4](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Understanding/consistent-identification.html).
3. If it is not possible to bypass both navigation menus, then it will be a violation of [SC 2.4.1](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Understanding/bypass-blocks.html).